# MySQL duplicate key update for group sub query

Tags: mysql

There are some related questions and answers but none solves my problem.

I have a table `regionviews`. It has a PK `region` and a column `views`.

I try the following query but there is an error (unknown column '`v`'):

```
INSERT INTO regionviews
(SELECT region, sum(views) v FROM tb GROUP BY region)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + v;
```

Can someone fix this query?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing an AS:

```
INSERT INTO regionviews
(SELECT region, sum(views) AS v FROM tb GROUP BY region)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + v;
```

Comment: What are the fields in your `tb` table?